# What is an easy tool/app for debugging(stepping through) PHP code?

Tags: php, debugging

I've tried to use Eclipse on Linux but was not able to get it to work after about 4 hours of trying and regressed to just inserting echo comments everywhere like I had been doing.

Now when I debug my Javascript in IE, I just hit F12 and a few more keys and I'm stepping through the Javascript.

I'm back on Windows so I need a Window Solution that is hopeufully simple, I'm not lazy - just pressed for time.

It would be cool if once javascript passed control to PHP, the debugger just kept stepping into the PHP, but does this even exist?

Comment: "javascript passed control to PHP"?  What do you mean by this?  Are you doing synchronous ajax?

Comment: A number of similar and better QAs haven been closed for being off-topic. Plus, this is heavily outdated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for something like **[FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/)** or **[ChromePHP](http://www.chromephp.com/)**. Those are Firefox and Chrome extensions which allow you to display anything that your PHP script output during runtime in either **[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)** (needs to be installed in Firefox) or native Chrome Developer Tools (doesn't require any extension in Chrome).

Keep in mind though that they are merely capable of displaying messages from your script and don't offer options such as watches, breakpoints etc.

A full-blooded PHP debugger / profiler like **[xDebug](http://xdebug.org/)** would still be a better solution in my opinion offering you a much better and leaner way of debugging.

Comment: I second the xDebug solution.  It is the best way to debug php (in my opinion)

Comment: @Robin, @ holodoc, Isn't xDebug just a library? I don't get it, can you actually set breakpoints and step through PHP with xDebug?

Comment: @Pacerier xdebug is a PHP extension which means it's loaded on top of the core functionality provided by the Zend engine itself. Basically, xdebug expands the capabilities of the core PHP module. And yes, combined with an IDE that supports debugging you can debug your code with breakpoints (even conditional ones), do on the fly evaluations etc. There are also command line debuggers too if you are into stuff like that.

Comment: @holodoc, Extending Zend engine itself, hm... sounds like it might lead to Heisenbugs though. Have you tried xDebug personally?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes I have used all the major PHP debuggers out there. xDebug is not perfect however it provides support for multiple platforms and comes with a built in profiler, which is a nice little addition.

Answer (score 1):

FirePHP is a good dubugger for PHP scripts.

Comment: Essentially though isnt that pretty much the same as doing `echo` statements with the exception of the nicety of it going to the FireBug console? (ive never used it but thats the impression i got...)

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans for php, Chrome netbeans extension and configure Netbeans to use internal php web server. It runs out of the box.